# How can I get multiple occurences from multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I get records from my database like so,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT id, username, loginIP FROM accounts");
$q -> execute();
while ($accounts = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      var_dump($accounts);
}
```

This gets me all the usernames and id and ips of users,

How can I check for multiple occurences of IPS? The IP are stored using `ip2long`, I have tried the following,

```
 $multiple = array_diff($accounts, array_unique($accounts));
 var_dump($multiple);
```

But it didn't work?

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple occurences of IPs?` you want to know the count of each unique IP in the array?

Comment: Why won't you check it by the SQL request?

Comment: And how would I do that? I don't know a mysql function that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative version - use SQL request to find the duplicates. Something like this:

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT a.id, a.username, a.loginIP FROM accounts a, 
             (SELECT loginIP FROM accounts GROUP BY loginIP HAVING COUNT(*)>1) d 
              WHERE d.loginIP = a.loginIP");
$q -> execute();
$accounts = array();
while ($acc = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $accounts[$acc['loginIP']] = $acc;
}
var_dump($accounts);
```

Only duplicates will appear in $accounts with IPs as array keys.

Comment: @cgwebprojects  You are welcome :) Sorry, there was a one-letter typo here `d.loginIP = a.loginIP`, but I think you saw it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming, based on the data you are querying and the way you state the question, that you are looking for ip addresses that are tied to multiple users because you either

a.  Want to see how many real users are tied to a single ip
b.  Find out how many duplicated accounts, coming from the same person have been made.

I think something like this does what you are after.

```
<?php

$ip_accounts = array();

// This whole step could be done within the while loop, as shown by Josh.
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
  $ip = $account['loginIP'];
  unset($account['loginIP']);
  if (! isset($ip_accounts[$ip])) {
    $ip_accounts[$ip] = array();
  }
  $ip_accounts[$ip][] = $account;
}

function multi_accounts($ip_account) {
  return count($ip_account) > 1;
}

$many_accounts = array_filter($ip_accounts, 'multi_accounts');
print_r($many_accounts);
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
[3232235821] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [username] => u22
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33
                [username] => u33
            )

    )

[3232235830] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 25
                [username] => u25
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 31
                [username] => u31
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 51
                [username] => u51
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 91
                [username] => u91
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 92
                [username] => u92
            )

    )
```