# PHP - MySQL , Sort clones

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I have mysql database with table users.  In users there are columns: 
`id , username , password , ip`

I have administration panel and I need to show users that have same ip , like this

User1 → User2

Nick1 → Nick2

etc.

How can i do it with php.Thanks , and this is urgent.Thanks.

Comment: Recently, almost the same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9197999/1164491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your sql query.

```
SELECT username, list.ip FROM users
INNER JOIN (SELECT ip FROM users
GROUP BY ip HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON list.ip = dup.ip
```

For use in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, list.ip FROM users
INNER JOIN (SELECT ip FROM users
GROUP BY ip HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON list.ip = dup.ip";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this query instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE ip in 
(SELECT username FROM users GROUP BY ip HAVING count(ip) > 1)";
```

Comment: tHANKS FOR YOUR answer , but for what is used list.ip and dup.ip ? Thanks.

Comment: the derived table/join pointless. a simple `select ... group by ... having ...` would have done the job as just as well without the join overhead.

Comment: I updated the answer above, try that query instead. I might be a little confused as to what you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
select users 
from users_table 
where ip ='thisIp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your list of duplicate IP's like this, 
    `SELECT COUNT(*) as acount, ip FROM users GROUP BY ip HAVING acount > 1`
then using those results, get all accounts that match those IP's